# Extract JSON | API | Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am using the Facebook API (v2.10) to which I've extracted the data I need, 95% of which is perfect. My problem is the '**actions**' metric which returns as a dictionary within a list within another dictionary.

At present, all the data is in a DataFrame, however, the 'actions' column is a list of dictionaries that contain each individual action for that day.

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "7"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "3"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "144"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "34"
        }]}
```

All this appears in one cell (row) within the DataFrame.

What is the best way to:

- Get the action type, create a new column and use the Use "action_type" as the column name?
- List the correct value under this column

It looks like JSON but when I look at the type, it's a panda series (stored as an object).

For those willing to help (thank you, I greatly appreciate it) - can you either point me in the direction of the right material and I will read it and work it out on my own (I'm not entirely sure what to look for) or if you decide this is an easy problem, explain to me how and why you solved it this way. Don't just want the answer

I have tried the following (with help from a friend) and it kind of works, but I have issues with this running in my script. IE: if it runs within a bigger code block, I get the following error:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    line = df.loc[i, 'Conversions']
    L = ast.literal_eval(line)
    for l in L:
        cid = l['action_type']
        value = l['value']
        df.loc[i, cid] = value
```

If I save the DF as a csv, call it using `pd.read_csv`...it executes properly, but not within the script. No idea why.

Error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'value': '1', 'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxx}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Is this just one cell, i.e. you have a whole column of these and you want to expand them somehow?

Comment: Correct, this one column as 214 individual cells based on the actions from that day, ad group, age, gender etc. I want to expand the individual actions and create unique columns for them

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
In [11]: d  # e.g. dict from json.load OR instead pass the json path to json_normalize
Out[11]:
{'actions': [{'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx',
   'value': '7'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx', 'value': '144'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx', 'value': '34'}]}

In [12]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, record_path="actions")
Out[12]:
                             action_type value
0  offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx     7
1  offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx     3
2  offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx   144
3  offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx    34
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy! Appreciate you helping.

I've tried to replicate the above using the below:

`d = df['Conversions']`
`pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, record_path="actions")`

Returned the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. 

Although it looks like JSON, the type actually returns a pandas series (as an object), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AdrianC Is it something like this: `df.actions.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({a["action_type"]: a["value"] for a in x["actions"]}))` that you want?

Comment: Thanks (again) Andy! I tried this, but it keeps returning the same error. 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. What you did above is close, however, instead of them running as rows, I need them to run as columns with the values underneath

Comment: are the entries dicts or string (that look like dicts)? If the latter, then you can hit the column with `df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).apply...`

Comment: They look like dicts, but from all the errors I'm getting, I would say strings which the following error would confirm: `ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'value': '1', 'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxx'}`

Comment: @AdrianC please try: `import ast; df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({a["action_type"]: a["value"] for a in x["actions"]}))`

Comment: This is similar to what I had in my question (which worked), but the above didn't (but looks like it should). Keep getting that same value error.

Comment: @AdrianC it's probably easier if you %debug into it, then you can narrow this error down

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['Conversions'].tolist()).pivot(columns='action_type', values='value').reset_index(drop=True))`.

Explanation:
`df['Conversions'].tolist()` returns a list of dictionaries. This list is then transformed into a DataFrame using pd.DataFrame. Then, you can use the [pivot function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to pivot the table into the shape that you want.

Lastly, you can join the table with your original DataFrame. Note that this only works if you DataFrame's index is the default (i.e., integers starting from 0). If this is not the case, you can do this instead:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Conversions'].tolist()).pivot(columns='action_type', values='value').reset_index(drop=True)
for col in df2.columns:
    df[col] = df2[col]`

Comment: This is actually very close but would like the action_type as the column name and the value in the cell.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Rishabh! Sadly, no. Get the following error: `KeyError: 'value'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: Are you using pandas 0.21.0? If not, what version of pandas are you using? You can find this out by `print pd.__version__`

Comment: I am using 20.3... will updating fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does the code snippet below run without an error on your machine?

```d = {
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "7"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "144"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.123xxxxxxxxx",
            "value": "34"
        }]}; df = pd.DataFrame(d['actions']); print df.pivot(columns='action_type', values='value')
```

Comment: Yes, this runs on my machine